# Iterate over a array in with_items loop

Tags: ansible

Based on this question

[Ansible recursive checks in playbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254122/ansible-recursive-checks-in-playbooks)

I have another one.

We need to go through this structure

Zone spec https://gist.github.com/git001/9230f041aaa34d22ec82eb17d444550c

Now I can adress the hostnames via the array index but can I also iterate over the array "**hosts**"?

playbook

```
--
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
    - "../doc/application-zone-spec.yml"

  roles:
    - { role: ingress_add, customers: "{{ application_zone_spec }}" }
```

role

```
 - name: Print ingress hostnames
   debug: msg="{{ item.hosts.0.hostname }} {{ item.hosts.1.hostname }}"
   with_items: "{{ customers.ingress }}"
```

We use.

```
ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.1.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `with_subelements`:

```
 - name: Print ingress hostnames
   debug: msg="{{ item.0.type }} {{ item.1.hostname }}"
   with_subelements:
     - "{{ customers.ingress }}"
     - "hosts"
```

There is quite a bit of examples for different loops in [the Loops section of the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html).

Comment: thanks. I have read the doc but haven't understand that I can just use any part of the struct in the **with_subelements** part.